# Ubuntu 22.04 Bluetooth Issues (Not Connecting To Bluetooth Device)

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, disconnect

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and the Bluetooth was working fine.
I turned off the Bluetooth and could not turn it back on.

I did some research and found some calls to turn it back on:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

Now, I can turn it on and off as I please but It is now not connecting to any device.
It would connect for a brief second and then disconnect.  Can't find anything from research.  Anyone can help with this ?

Also,
Whenever I boot up windows, the bluetooth works perfectly fine on windows.  So it's not an hardware issue.

I ran the command: `bluetoothctl` 
As you see in the screenshot, it is cycling through connecting to the device and disconnecting.

[image]

I ran `sudo journalctl  -b 0 | grep blue`

And get the following (in screenshot)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Start by looking at the system logs: `sudo journalctl  -b 0` page through the logs, looking for bluetooth entries

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 1):

Just would like to add, every time the computer is restarted the Bluetooth does not turn on.  What I do is to run the following code to turn it on.  The device will auto connect or hit refresh on the saved device or re-add it to connect it.

```
### Hard Refresh

## End Service (If it is running)
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service

## Removes Hardware Emulation  
sudo systemctl unmask bluetooth.service

## Start Service
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth

## Re-Enable Hardware Emulation
sudo systemctl mask bluetooth.service 
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb

## Unblock from rfkill
rfkill unblock all
```

---

Issue Resolved!

All I did was to remove the device and re-add it.

[image]
[image]